# XPATH Syntax Help - Get Value Based on Peer Value

Tags: xml, xpath

I am trying to understand how I can setup an XPath that helps me locate in the following file the value for `serialdata` only when `serialname` is `'Motion'`.

I want to get the value of a sibling node based upon the value of a given node.

```
<file>
  <error>0</error>
  <gls>
    <mtsn>123</mtsn>
    <asset>
      <assetid>n/a</assetid>
      <assettype>None</assettype>
      <owner>My Company</owner>
    </asset>
    <messagetype>Event</messagetype>
    <binary>
      <inputname>Tether</inputname>
      <inputid>15</inputid>
      <event>E</event>
      <inputval>1</inputval>
      <inputstate>Tether</inputstate>
      <timeofreading>2014/01/22 16:50:30</timeofreading>
    </binary>
    <extpwr>0</extpwr>
    <serial>
      <serialtype>2</serialtype>
      <serialid>3</serialid>
      <serialname>Motion</serialname>
      <serialdata>Idle</serialdata>
    </serial>
    <serial>
      <serialtype>2</serialtype>
      <serialid>5</serialid>
      <serialname>Cargo</serialname>
      <serialdata>No answer</serialdata>
    </serial>
    <latitude>40.40299</latitude>
    <longitude>-86.85927</longitude>
    <battery>OK</battery>
    <time>2014/01/22 16:50:30</time>
    <quality>0</quality>
    <landmark>
      <geoname>Lafayette</geoname>
      <state>IN</state>
      <country>US</country>
      <distance>0.81</distance>
      <direction>SE</direction>
      <geotypename>GENERIC</geotypename>
    </landmark>
    <skyfence>
      <skyfencestatus>n/a</skyfencestatus>
    </skyfence>
    <epmflag>0</epmflag>
    <transid>21722229</transid>
  </gls>
</file>
```

Comment: well the xml didn't post correctly. Not sure how to make that happen.

Comment: I believe it may be: /file/gls/serial[serialname='Motion']/serialdata/text()

Comment: You can test xpath here http://www.xpathtester.com/test

Comment: @user1224074 you can post this as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your xml seems to be incomplete or incorrect.

Try this xpath for below example xml:

//serial[serialname="Motion"]/serialdata

example xml:

```
<serial>
  <serialtype>2</serialtype>
  <serialid>3</serialid>
  <serialname>Motion</serialname>
  <serialdata>Idle</serialdata>
</serial>  
<serial>
  <serialtype>2</serialtype>
  <serialid>5</serialid>
  <serialname>Cargo</serialname>
  <serialdata>No answer</serialdata>
</serial>
```